# VirtualBox does not work

Tags: 11.10, virtualbox

VirtualBox does not run on my ubuntu 11.10 32 bit OS.
 When I type VirtualBox in the terminal I get:

`keghn@keghn-laptop:~$ VirtualBox
VirtualBox: supR3HardenedMainGetTrustedMain: dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox.so",) failed: /usr/local/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0: undefined symbol: DirectFBCreate.`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: is there a libSDL-1.2.so.0 in /usr/lib/ ?

Comment: How did you install VirtualBox ?  If you do not have a libSDL-1.2.so.0 you can install it with `sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian`

Answer (score 4):

`/usr/local/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0` that's not something from an Ubuntu package. Ubuntu packages don't have anything in `/usr/local`, so it came from somewhere else. It's also what's causing the trouble. Figure out if it's something you need, and remove it if not.

Did you install your virtualbox from the Ubuntu repositories? If you didn't, I suggest that you do.